# R: Extracting string if it is an element of a list

Tags: r, string, stringr

I want to dummy-code whether some string is contained in another (which is structured). For example:

```
player <- c("Michael Jordan", "Steve Kerr", "Michael Jordan", "Toni Kukoc")

bulls <- c("Jordan, Michael Jeffrey", "Pippen, Scottie; Harper, Ron",
           "Rodman, Dennis", "Kerr, Steve; Longley, Luc; Kukoc, Toni")
```

and create a new variable (say, `included`) if words Michael and Jordan are present in `bulls[1]`, Steve Kerr in `bulls[2]` etc. The above should produce `TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE`. For generality, names and surnames are separated by commas, whereas a semicolon indicates multiple people in a single entry. Given that the object `bulls` can feature longer versions of a name ("Jeffrey" in this case) but not the other way around, I suspect the solution might require some sort of an is.element check? I want to iterate this over a long list, what is the best approach?

p.s. I tried several `stringr` verbs, however no luck so far (_view, _extract etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(stringr)
mapply(function(x,y) all(x %in% y),
    str_extract_all(player,"\\w+"),str_extract_all(bulls,"\\w+"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, does exactly what I wanted in the larger dataset.